# Typography of sideways figure

Tags: typography, text, page-layout, latex

I'm writing my thesis using LaTeX and I have the following question. Since my figure is too wide to fit the layout, I rotate it using `sidewaysfigure` environment from `rotating` package. I'd like to clear out some typographical issues with respect to international and/or Czech typographical norms or conventions.

- Should the caption of the figure also be rotated (as sidewaysfigure does)? I assume it should.

  What about page number? Should it be put sideways or not or should it disappear completely since this is a special page?

This is a “manual mirror” of the following question on TeX.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188512/typography-of-sideways-figure

Comment: Please don't cross post duplicate questions across SE sites.

Comment: @DA01 Well it is not clear on which site it belongs. I first put it on TeX.SE and there was a suggestion that it is off-topic and that it may belong here. If there is clear resolution on where it belongs, I can delete the other one.

Comment: Yes, that's an understandable problem. As we have more and more SE sites, the overlap increases. I'd suggest keeping an eye on both and see which one is giving you the answers you need, then delete the other.

Answer (score 1):

The caption of an figure should be below the figure. So if you are looking on a figure you should be able to read the caption. If the figure is rotated the caption should be rotated too.

Because the page number usually has a fixed place were it is printed in a document I would not rotate the page number, I would just leave it out. But this is my opinion ...

Comment: I have similar opinion. This setting is also easiest one to achieve. There is just minor con with the page number when used together with the following idea: it is possible set the resulting PDF in a way that the whole page is rotated when viewed in PDF reader (so one doesn't have to turn head). But in this case the page number looks rotated the other way of course.

Comment: @user87690 I think you can rotate in each pdf viewer the view of one side (so no one had to turn the head). I saw an automatic changing, but I think it depends on the used pdf viewer. I guess Acrobat can do it, I do not remember which one did it. With LaTeX you can use the given packages to rotate the graphic and lay it over the page number. So it will not be displayed (with its wrong orientation). If you want to have the page number you can define an separate page layout in LaTeX. But I think that is not neccesary for only one special page ...